# Is maven required to install explicitly if already installed Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, eclipse-kepler

I have already installed Kepler in which maven comes inbuilt.

After that am I required to download Maven explicitly and set environment variable? or just downloading eclipse kepler version is fine?

Comment: it depends like if you want to run jetty server then you need to install on machine also...

Answer (score 0):

The plugin in Eclipse is a different thing from Maven using on command line. So you have to download Maven and install it locally which has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Comment: I would appreciate if you explain difference between them.

Comment: The plugin in Eclipse m2e is a plugin which supports developing projects with Maven support. Maven itself is an independent project build tool. What would you like to know?